# Count and list all polygon features within a polygon in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-join, overlapping-features, count

I am trying to count and list the names of all individual layers that have polygons (in blue and green) within multiple target polygons (one example shown in orange) in a separate layer using ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

The goal is to get a list of all different features included in the target polygons, what they are and how many of them (number of individual polygons) are present and, ideally, calculate the area they occupy within the target polygons. The layers to be counted are very large and all have different sets of attributes.

As I have quite a few individual layers ideally this can be done as a batch analyses. I've tried Spatial Join, Summarize Within and Count Overlapping Features but these tools either do not offer a batch option or dissolve the layers in a way that the required information is lost. Any ideas on how to go about this in ArcGIS Pro without having to deal with massive merged files?

Comment: Select Layer By Location should do the job.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. How would you proceed after having all the layers selected though?

Comment: You wanted a list of features overlapping a feature, right? Having selected the query feature (or defaulting to all), do a new selection on all the other features overlapping the selection set of the query feature class, then iterate the selected features in each feature class. DA SearchCursor honors the selection set of a layer. Add all the feature IDs or unique feature keys to a `list`. If you don't know how to do any of this, you need to break this question into a number of steps, and research each one separately.

Comment: That is a good way to address this, thank you. I fear I might not have been entirely clear (will edit the question accordingly) - my target layer has 128 polygons and I'd like to know the overlapping features with each of those. I will see if your suggested method can address this, thank you.